# How to use latin modern fonts in dvips?

Tags: dvi, dvips

Consider the following example:

```
\font\tenrm=rm-lmr10 \tenrm
a
\end
```

Run `tex` on it, and then `dvips`:

```
dvips: Font rm-lmr10 not found; using cmr10
dvips: Checksum mismatch in font rm-lmr10
```

As far as I understand, TeX did its job using `tfm` files. Now `dvips` needs to put corresponding `pfb` fonts to the DVI output and produce PostScript. What does `dvips` miss to do its job?

*NOTE: `pdftex` is not to be considered - only `tex`*

**EDIT**

After reinstalling system, PK font is now generated from Type1 by default. Why can that be?

```
This is dvips(k) 5.998 Copyright 2018 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2019.08.06:2048' -> lm.ps

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode ljfour --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 rm-lmbx10
mktexpk: Running gsftopk rm-lmbx10 600
gsftopk(k) version 1.19.2/926
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] [17]
[18] [19] [20] [21] [22] [23] [24] [25] [26] [27] [28] [29] [30] [31] [32] [33]
[34] [35] [36] [37] [38] [39] [40] [41] [42] [43] [44] [45] [46] [47] [48] [49]
[50] [51] [52] [53] [54] [55] [56] [57] [58] [59] [60] [61] [62] [63] [64] [65]
[66] [67] [68] [69] [70] [71] [72] [73] [74] [75] [76] [77] [78] [79] [80] [81]
[82] [83] [84] [85] [86] [87] [88] [89] [90] [91] [92] [93] [94] [95] [96] [97]
[98] [99] [100] [101] [102] [103] [104] [105] [106] [107] [108] [109] [110]
[111] [112] [113] [114] [115] [116] [117] [118] [119] [120] [121] [122] [123]
[124] [125] [126] [127] [128] [129] [130] [131] [132] [133] [134] [135] [136]
[137] [138] [139] [140] [141] [142] [143] [144] [145] [146] [147] [148] [149]
[150] [151] [152] [153] [154] [155] [156] [157] [158] [159] [160] [161] [162]
[163] [164] [165] [166] [167] [168] [169] [170] [171] [172] [173] [174] [175]
[176] [177] [178] [179] [180] [181] [182] [183] [184] [185] [186] [187] [188]
[189] [190] [191] [192] [193] [194] [195] [196] [197] [198] [199] [200] [201]
[202] [203] [204] [205] [206] [207] [208] [209] [210] [211] [212] [213] [214]
[215] [216] [217] [218] [219] [220] [221] [222] [223] [224] [225] [226] [227]
[228] [229] [230] [231] [232] [233] [234] [235] [236] [237] [238] [239] [240]
[241] [242] [243] [244] [245] [246] [247] [248] [249] [250] [251] [252] [253]
[254] [255]
mktexpk: /usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/pk/modeless/public/lm/rm-lmbx10.600pk: successfully generated.
</usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/pk/modeless/public/lm/rm-lmbx10.600pk>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>. [1]
```

Comment: you seem to be missing map files, what does `$ kpsewhich lm.map` show, it should be `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/lm/lm.map`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it gives `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/lm/lm.map`

Comment: That is OK (just a different texmf root). So I am not sure what to suggest, perhaps re-run `updmap-sys` to rebuild the map files, also do you have the pfb files (`texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb`)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and install the TUG TeX Live, rather than the version provided by your GNU/Linux distribution. Your life will be easier.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I have the `pfb` - the PK is generated from it, as seen in the log in **EDIT**. `updmap-sys` does not help - PK is generated automatically the same.

Comment: @egreg I'm almost sure that the reason is not Debian's version. It's interesting to find out what it is...

Comment: `texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg` says the following, so I think you need to track down your cfg and map files and check if any of them are specifying default to pk (oh didn't you comment on a previous answer that you had a non standard map set up?) # Should dvips (by default) prefer bitmap fonts or outline fonts
# if both are available? Independent of this setting, outlines
# can be forced by putting "p psfonts_t1.map" into a config file
# that dvips reads. Bitmaps (for the fonts in question) can
# be forced by putting "p psfonts_pk.map" into a config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out why this happens by disabling quiet mode in `dvips`:

```
This is dvips(k) 5.998 Copyright 2018 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2019.08.12:1246' -> x.ps

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode ljfour --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 rm-lmr10
mktexpk: Running gsftopk rm-lmr10 600
gsftopk(k) version 1.19.2gs: Error: /undefined in shellarguments
...
```

This means that the command to generate PK fonts from T1 fonts is started.
But in newer versions of Debian it fails for some reason...

---

The proper solution to use PK fonts is to use "p psfonts_pk.map" for `dvips`,
instead of "p /dev/null" in `.dvipsrc`.

Latin modern fonts' `pfb`s are listed in `psfonts_pk.map` already, so Type 1 will be used for them, as necessary.

This happens because in system updmap.cfg there is

```
Map lm.map
```

(compare this with `MixedMap cm.map`)

*NOTE: using `dvipsPreferOutline false` breaks metapost when fonts are embedded (`prologues:=3;`), so it should not be used*

Answer (score 3):

If I run tex then dvips on your test file then I get (texlive 2019)

```
This is dvips(k) 5.999 Copyright 2019 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2019.07.24:1017' -> cc051.ps
</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-rm.enc>
</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>. 
</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb>[1]
```

You seem to have an incomplete installation without `fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that I have `p /dev/null` in my `.dvipsrc`. Thus, I need to find MetaFont analog of `rm-lmr10`.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko the lm fonts are not written in metafont

Comment: `ecrm1000` works for me

Comment: @IgorLiferenko that font will work, but is far from being an answer to this question, it is not latin modern.  In LaTeX terms you have switched from `\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{lmr}` to `\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{cmr}`  so a different font family and a different encoding.

Comment: please see **EDIT**

Comment: See beginning of my answer. I found out why it works differently on different versions of Debian. But why `gsftopk` started to fail?

Comment: Seems like it's a bug. I reported it.

Comment: Recent versions of gs removed a lot of gs extensions to get closer to standard postscript and for some security issues, so that's probably the root cause but gsftopk (which I am fairly sure I have never used:-) probably ought to detect that and at least give a sensible error @IgorLiferenko